# CRNA, genymotion, expo weird error

Tags: react-native, genymotion, expo

I am using genymotion to run my React Native dev environment. When a specific component loads, I get the console.error message: `there was a problem sending log messages to your development environment` with a weird stack trace that uses `<unknown>` in place of several named functions.

I narrowed the problem down to just one component in my code:

```
class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  style: 'all',
                  selected: ''}
  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.questions}>
        <ScrollView>
          {(this.props.questions && this.state.style == 'all')&&
            this.props.questions.map(post => {
              return (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.loadQuestion(post)} key={post.ID + new Date(post.post_date)} style={styles.questionCard} >
                  <View style={styles.questionCard} >
                    <View style={styles.title}>
                      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{post.post_title}</Text>
                      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> - {post.display_name} {utils.timeSince(new Date(post.post_date))}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              )
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Whenever this component loads, I got the console.error mentioned above. I know this isn't much to go on and I don't really even expect an answer, but I'm at a loss.

If you google that exact error message you will find one issue on Github with no resolution, mentioning that it may be an error in the expo sdk (which makes sense) and linking another issue that 404s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay I think I solved it, the problem was actually in my utils function `timeSince`. I had a stray console.log() statement and when I removed it the error went away. Apparently with this configuration you cannot call console.log() from internal assets.

EDIT: Okay so after some further debugging, this error is thrown when you try to console.log() an object, it doesn't matter where the log originates.

Answer (score 0):

> Okay I think I solved it, the problem was actually in my utils function `timeSince`. I had a stray console.log() statement and when I removed it the error went away. Apparently with this configuration you cannot call console.log() from internal assets.
>
> EDIT: Okay so after some further debugging, this error is thrown when you try to console.log() an object, it doesn't matter where the log originates.

I hope this sheds some more light to the origin of this "error":

The object you are referring to is actually the response from the call, and it doesn't like it bc of the size. It's not any object, just the `response` object from a call. If you try destructuring the part you want, then it goes away

Comment: Please include a complete answer *here*, don't ask people looking for solutions to a problem to go follow links to other pages to get the problem solved. If this question is really a duplicate of the other question, then don't answer, wait for enough reputation to be able to flag as a duplicate instead.