# React-native: Problem sending log - console.error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working with Expo React native, I'm trying to send POST request to my express server using axios

**App.js - in my React**

```
Axios({
   url:'http://172.20.1.19:3001/api/tracking/locator',
   method:'POST',
   data:{
      test:'wew'
   },
   config:'JSON',
   headers:{
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
   }
})
.then(res=>{
   console.log(res)
})
.catch(err=>{
   console.log(err)
})
```

In node status its 200, but when console.log the response it throws an error

> console.error. "There was a problem sending log message to your
>   development environment",

**Tracking.js - Express**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router()
const app = express();


const db = require('../models');

app.use(cors({origin:'http://172.20.1.19:19001'}));


router.get('/', function(req, res, next){ 
    res.json({
        data: {
            test :'wew'
        }
    })
})


router.post('/locator', function(req,res,next){
    res.json({
        data:{
            status:'pano mo nasabe'
        }
    })
})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRNA, genymotion, expo weird error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364675/crna-genymotion-expo-weird-error)

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use:**

(this helped me)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
```

**or**

```
console.log(response.data)
```

**also**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```