# Upload image to firestore convert to blob throws Error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, blob

Why i can not log the value of response?
I mean i wait for the response why i get this error?

```
export const uploadProfileImage = async (pickedImage) => {
  const user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const fileExtension = pickedImage.uri.split('.').pop();
  const fileName = `profile.${fileExtension}`;
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${user_id}/profile/${fileName}`);

  const response = await fetch(pickedImage.uri);
  const file_blob = await response.blob();

  console.log(response) => throws the error or any other log which is commented out.
  
  storageRef.put(file_blob).on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    snapshot => {
      // console.log("snapshot", snapshot) 
    },
    error => {
      // console.log("uploadProfileImage Error", error); unsubscribe(); 
    },
    complete => {
      // console.log("uploadProfileImage", complete);
    }
  )
}
```

```
console.error: There was a problem sending log messages to your development enviroment. 
Error: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. 
(In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined.
```

Please can anyone explain this to me.

I do not understand this behavior.

And is there a another way to convert an local image path to blob?
So i can put the blob in the firestore function "put".

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  The question should contain enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue.  What you have right now is too vague.

Comment: @DougStevenson: I expect that i can log in the console the response object to see how it looks like. Or is this not possible? And if i try console.log(response) i get the error. I don't know why

Comment: Hi @juri88 it seems that it's related to `value.hasOwnProperty`, however, we can't confirm that, as there isn't this part of your code within what you have added. Considering that, could you please try one of the workarounds available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55836322/12767257)? In case they don't help, please, update your question, adding the `hasOwnProperty()` part to it.